# WARNING: pyjwt 1.1.0 does not provide the extra 'crypto'

Tags: python-3.x, docker, django-rest-framework, pip, pyjwt

I am getting the error

> WARNING: pyjwt 1.1.0 does not provide the extra 'crypto'

for Docker command

```
RUN pip install --no-cache /wheels/*
```

while installing PyJWT==1.7.1, Is there any solution to fix this warning?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In order to fix the following warning

> WARNING: You are using pip version 20.1.1; however, version 21.0 is
> available. You should consider upgrading via the
> '/usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

I added the following code to Dockerfile

```
# upgrade pip
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
```

I just reverted adding this and it now works correctly, although I still have the pip version warning.

Answer (score 2):

PyJWT 1.7.1 [was released](https://pypi.org/project/PyJWT/1.7.1/) at Dec 7, 2018.

Extra `crypto` was added to PyJWT [on Oct 22, 2019](https://github.com/jpadilla/pyjwt/commit/11ac89474b1179925c76450fcc4b3d2042c45f19#diff-60f61ab7a8d1910d86d9fda2261620314edcae5894d5aaa236b821c7256badd7R37) hence it's available in PyJWT 2.0+.

To use `pyjwt[crypto]` you need to install later version. Currently the latest is PyJWT 2.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

You can install `pyjwt` with the cryptographic Dependency with:

```
pip install pyjwt[crypto]
```

As seen in [pyjwt's documentation](https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html#cryptographic-dependencies-optional)

You can also separately install the required library with as seen on [pyca/cryptography's documentation](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/):

```
pip install cryptography
```

Comment: still the same result